# Detectar se uma determinada página é aberta dentro de um IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Gostaria de saber se é possível detectar a seguinte situação:

1. Temos uma intranet (de uma diretoria) que é carregada através de um dado endereço: http:intr.abcdabcd.abc.br
2. Temos uma INTRANET global, dentro da primeira página da intranet Global, a intranet da DIRETORIA é carregada dentro um IFRAME (então o atributo SRC desse IFRAME é >> "http:intr.abcdabcd.abc.br"

Questão, é possível, dentro da página que responde pelo endereço "http:intr.abcdabcd.abc.br" eu detectar que "estou sendo" aberta dentro de um IFRAME?

Objetivo, caso eu detecte que estou sendo aberta dentro de um IFRAME ajustar a apresentação.

Atenciosamente,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você pode tentar acessar `window.frameElement`, caso `frameElement` seja nulo, é por que você não está dentro de um `iFrame`.

Comment: Só faltou um exemplozinho :)

Answer (score 5):

Tem sim, você pode fazer como expliquei em [JavaScript - Diferença entre `this` e `self`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/201986/3635), então dentro da página que possivelmente pode ser chamada dentro do iframe adicione isto:

```
if (window.top !== window.self) {
    alert('Esta página foi provavelmente chamada dentro de um iframe');
} else {
    alert('Esta página foi aberta diretamente na aba/janela');
}
```

O que cada propriedade faz:

- `window.self` retorna o objeto da janela atual
- `window.top` retorna o objeto da janela acima de todas, por exemplo se uma página tiver um iframe chamado `#frame1` e este iframe tiver outro iframe chamado `#frame2`, então em `#frame2` usar `window.top` ele irá retornar o objeto página que embarcou o `#frame1`

Você também pode querer checar se o domínio for o mesmo que o seu domínio então não ocorre a função, por exemplo:

```
if (window.top.location.host !== window.location.host) {
    alert('Sua página foi embarcada por um dominio diferente');
} else if (window.top !== window.self) {
    alert('sua página foi provavelmente embarcada por uma página do mesmo dominio');
} else {
    alert('Esta página foi aberta diretamente na aba/janela');
}
```

### Redirecionando

Se você deseja redirecionar para o seu próprio site você pode usar `.location = ...` ou `.location.replace(...)`, a diferença entre ambos é que `location.replace` vai substituir a página atual, fazendo com que a página que tinha iframe **não** fique disponível no *back* e *forward*, o que pode ser mais interessante, exemplo:

```
if (window.top !== window.self) {
    alert('Este site não permite enquadramentos (frame), você esta sendo redirecionado'); //Mensagem opicional
    window.top.location.replace(window.self.location.href);
}
```

### X-Frame-Options

No entanto um coisa interessante que você pode usar para impedir o *embed* (se for o que deseja) é usar o header `X-Frame-Options`, que pode ser adicionado via linguagem *server-side* ou até via .htaccess, web.config, etc. Existem 3 valores possíveis:

- `X-Frame-Options: DENY`

  Impede o embed usando frame ou iframe de qualquer site, até mesmo o próprio site
- `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`

  Impede que site com domínios diferentes do seu embarquem sua(s) página(s), mas se for o mesmo domínio então poderá embarcar
- `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://sitepermitido.com/`

  Permite um site especifico embarcar sua(s) página(s).

Exemplos com `SAMEORIGIN`:

- **.htaccess**:

  ```bsh
  Header add X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
  ```
- **web.config** (o `...` é para indiciar que pode adicionar mais configurações):

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
         <httpProtocol>
              <customHeaders>
                  <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
                  ...
              </customHeaders>
          </httpProtocol>
          ...
      </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
  ```
- **nginx.conf**:

  ```
  location pasta_especifica {
       add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;      
  }
  ```
- **PHP**:

  ```php
  <?php
  header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
  ```
- **asp.net** (em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), creio que não seja muito diferente se escrito em vb.net)

  ```c#
  Response.AppendHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você possa utilizar a propriedade `parent` (A reference to the parent of the current window or subframe.), e ate mesmo ser mais especifico como pegando o endereço da janela que contem o iframe.

```
parent.location.href
```

Para mais informações você pode utilizar o link abaixo.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent