# iframe não funciona com sites externos

Tags: html, iframe

Estou desenvolvendo um painel com vários iframes, porém, colocando sites externos como `google.com.br` não está abrindo nada no iframe

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>ADM</h1>
        <iframe src="http://google.com.br"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Resultado: https://educapp-davidev.c9users.io/admin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É porque o seu site usa HTTPS e você esta tentando injetar em um site HTTP, então causa o erro:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://educapp-davidev.c9users.io/admin/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://google.com.br/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Talvez isto usar HTTPS no seu site e HTTPS no iframe, talvez funcione:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>ADM</h1>
        <iframe src="https://google.com.br"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Mas lembre-se **existem outros** tipos de bloqueios, como os headers `Frame-Options` e `Content-Security-Policy` que site externos podem estar usando

mais detalhes em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205939/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75492/3635

---

### Alternativa

A alternativa é algo complexo e não tem garantias, você pode criar uma especie de proxy com `CURL` dentro do teu servidor para acessar sites externos.

Crie um arquivo chamado `webproxy.php` e adicione

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if (empty($_GET['url']) || preg_match('#^(http|https)://[a-z0-9]#i', $_GET['url']) === 0) {
    echo 'URL inválida';
    exit;
}

$url = $_GET['url'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

//Envia o user agente do navegador atual
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Pega os dados
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//Fecha o curl
curl_close($ch);

$ch = NULL;

$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($data === false) {
    http_response_code(404);
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} elseif ($httpcode !== 200) {
    http_response_code($httpcode);
} else {
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    header('Content-Type: ' . $finfo->buffer($data));
    echo $data;
}
```

E solicitar no iframe por:

```
<iframe src="webproxy.php?url=https://google.com.br"></iframe>
```

Comment: Troquei para HTTPS e não foi

Comment: @DaviDEV mesmo que vc coloque HTTP o google força HTTPS com redirecionamento.

Comment: Há alguma maneiro de abrir sites com o bloqueio `Content-Security-Policy`?

Comment: @DaviDEV tenta usar HTTPS em ambos, sobre o `Content-Security-Policy` não tem como, se não seria uma falha de segurança.

Comment: É porque na verdade eu estou tentando abrir o PagSeguro... Mais tranquilo, obrigado amigo!

Comment: @DaviDEV melhor abrir o pagseguro da maneira indicada na API deles.

Comment: Eu quero colocar vários iframes do lado do outro, um do pag, outro com outras coisas tendeu

Comment: @DaviDEV entender eu entendi sim, o problema é que você esta querendo "enfeitar" as coisas talvez sem necessidade, o melhor é usar conforme a documentação deles (pagseguro) informou, fora que um monte de iframes é mais uma incomodo para o usuário do que facilitador. ;)