# Iframe em branco

Tags: html, iframe, ssl

Preciso de um Iframe no meu site. Meu site tem protocolo HTTPS, e o source do Iframe também. Então, por que o meu site não o exibe? Ambos sites tem certificado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="index,follow" />
<link rel="icon" href="/site/img/layout/favicon.png" />
<style>.se-pre-con { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:100%; height: 100%; z-index: 9999; background: url(/site/img/layout/preloader.svg) center no-repeat #3177fa; }</style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/css/script/jquery-ui-delta/jquery-ui.css">        
        <title>Teste</title>
    </head>
    <body id="home">
        <h1>Teste</h1>
        <iframe src="https://sandbox-app.vindi.com.br/customer/bills/6740?token=1fd4b0cc-2f66-4b3e-9bac-7c9988e64646" width="100%" height="50%"></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [iframe não funciona com sites externos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226853/iframe-n%c3%a3o-funciona-com-sites-externos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema nada tem haver com SSL/HTTPS, a mensagem de erro é:

> Refused to display `'https://sandbox-app.vindi.com.br/customer/bills/6740?token=1fd4b0cc-2f66-4b3e-9bac-7c9988e64646'` in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Ou seja o site `https://sandbox-app.vindi.com.br/customer/bills/6740?token=1fd4b0cc-2f66-4b3e-9bac-7c9988e64646` contém no cabeçalho/header HTTP a seguinte configuração:

```
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
```

O que quer dizer que permite somente usar como frame se for no mesmo dominio, logo se você não tem controle sobre o dominio `sandbox-app.vindi.com.br` será impossivel injetar diretamente ele em seu site via Iframe.

---

### Solução alternativa (webproxy)

Um exemplo de solução alternativa é usar uma linguagem que rode no seu servidor, pelo que vi você usa PHP (com o tempo adiciono exemplos em outras linguagens) então fiz este exemplo em outra pergunta com mesmo problema https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/226854/3635:

**webproxy.php**

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if (empty($_GET['url']) || preg_match('#^(http|https)://[a-z0-9]#i', $_GET['url']) === 0) {
    echo 'URL inválida';
    exit;
}

$url = $_GET['url'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

//Envia o user agente do navegador atual
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Pega os dados
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//Fecha o curl
curl_close($ch);

$ch = NULL;

$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($data === false) {
    http_response_code(404);
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} elseif ($httpcode !== 200) {
    http_response_code($httpcode);
} else {
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    header('Content-Type: ' . $finfo->buffer($data));
    echo $data;
}
```

E solicitar no iframe por:

```
<?php
//Codifica a url para passar via GET
$url = urlencode('https://sandbox-app.vindi.com.br/customer/bills/6740?token=1fd4b0cc-2f66-4b3e-9bac-7c9988e64646');
?>

<iframe src="webproxy.php?url=<?php echo $url; ?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Oi Guilherme, obrigado pela explicação. Como você fez para detectar o motivo do refused? Via debugger? O meu não mostrou nada... Outra coisa: Eu não posso exibir desta maneira, pois esta mesma URL contém dependendo da situação do pagamento, pode aparecer só a fatura (como está hoje) ou mostrar as opções de pagamento e fazê-lo. Então, infelizmente não conseguirei colocar no site desta maneira mesmo :/

Comment: @MaykelEsser no console do navegador, no Chrome e Firefox o atalho é F12